# EmberJS - How to dynamically generate link with linkTo?

Tags: ember.js

Is there a way to dynamically generate a link using the [`link-to`](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.13.0/templates/links/) helper by passing a variable with the route path?

For example, instead of hard coding the path like this:

```
{{#linkTo "route.subroute" model}}{{model.title}}{{/linkTo}}
```

I want to be able to pass the [`link-to`](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.13.0/templates/links/) helper a variable which holds the path like this:

```
{{#linkTo destination model}}{{model.title}}{{/linkTo}}
```

The use case for this is to allow me to consolidate templates which only differ by this path. For instance, if there are two collections each with a different destination. When rendered with the each helper the templates are the same except for the path in the [`link-to`](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.13.0/templates/links/).

If I could save this variable in the view’s controller and pass it, I could use only one template for both the lists.

I have thought about manually constructing the path like this:

```
<a {{bindAttr href="destination"}}>{{model.title}}</a>
```

But this does not have the integration with the router to determine the active state which I need.

Comment: seeing https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/2252 and https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/2462 I think it's currently just not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to dynamically generate a link using the linkTo helper by passing a variable with the route path?

Not at the moment.

> The use case for this is to allow me to consolidate templates which only differ by this path. For instance, if there are two collections each with a different destination.

Agreed this is a valid use case, I would expect linkTo helper to support it in future. Meantime since you've only got two collections you could accomplish this with conditionals in the template

```
{{#if isRouteOne}}
  {{#linkTo "routeOne.subrouteOne" model}}{{model.title}}{{/linkTo}}
{{else}}
  {{#linkTo "routeTwo.subrouteTwo" model}}{{model.title}}{{/linkTo}}
{{/if}}
```

Comment: Well, I wrote 'two' as a simplification of the problem; unfortunately, I actually have 7.  Having a to manage that many boolean variables is going to be rather tedious, but for simpler cases I still like the answer as a temporary work around.

Comment: lol agreed with 7 it's not going to be fun. in that case might make sense to write a small handlebars helper. hopefully the PR @sly7_7 mentioned will get merged in soon.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `{{linkTo}}`,you can use `{{action}}` and handle the event of transition by route name specify in `destination` property of model.

Comment: He needs the "active" support.

Answer (score 0):

There is another very similar SO Question in which I [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39904092/3711334) this question. The solution is possible using the **inline** version of the `link-to` helper.

In this situation, we would have:

```
{{link-to model.title destination model}}
```

Which would be compiled to:

```
<a href="#/route/subroute/3856">
  Click me
</a>
```