# Customizing URLs in Ember's #linkTo helper

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

One of the templates in my Ember application contains a link. Currently, I'm using the #linkTo helper as follows:

```
{{#linkTo project.index project}}Link{{/linkTo}}
```

However, I'd like to change it so the `href` attribute of the link is dependent on a controller property. Specifically, in my project-related controller, I'd like the link to appear as above. And when the template is rendered under my search-related controller, I'd like the link to appear follows:

```
{{#linkTo search.index search}}Link{{/linkTo}}
```

The only problem is that it doesn't seem possible to use controller properties to populate the arguments sent to #linkTo. Am I missing something? Alternatively, I tried using `{{bindAttr}}` to build my own link:

```
<a {{bindAttr href="path"}}>Link</a>
```

From here, I would add a `path` property to my controller that returns the desired path. The problem here, however, is I have no idea how to programmatically generate the desired path (e.g. the path for `project.index` should be `/project/:id` in my app), and I'd prefer not to hard-code it.

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [EmberJS - How to dynamically generate link with linkTo?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16021148/emberjs-how-to-dynamically-generate-link-with-linkto)